# how to using group by for relationships in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, database, polymorphism, backend

how to join in morph relations and how to make group inside another group

and also I need count of statuses

```
TicketHistory::groupBy('from_id')
            ->with(['statuses' => function ($query) {
                return $query->groupBy('name');
            }])->get();


TicketHistory::query()
            ->groupBy('from_id')
            ->join('model_statuses', 'ticket_history.id', '=', 'model_statuses.model_id')
            ->selectRaw('count(model_statuses.id) as count, status_count')
            ->groupBy('status_count')
            ->get();
```

- groupby from_id
- and then in from_id groupby statuses
- and there are 2 table with morph relation
- and there are 2 table with morph relation

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please explain what are you seeking for and what is the problem with your solution.

Comment: its just grouping by from_id not status

Answer (score 0):

```
 $ticketHistories = $ticketHistoryQuery->get()
            ->groupBy(
                [
                    'from_id',
                    function ($item) {
                        return $item->status;
                    }
                ],
                $preserveKeys = true
            );
```

this one is working but its too slowly

Comment: You should not post question in answer. Delete this answer and add it to your question as an update.